# How to export react app to pure static html

Tags: html, reactjs

Like the title, I have a landing page written by reactJS, it's small and I want to export to pure static html. I've researched and not found any solution.

Comment: you need to build for production then only you can get static file

Comment: Basically you need to build it to get all the static files, if you used create-react-app, you can find more about deployment here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way to build a react app in a single html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949719/is-there-a-way-to-build-a-react-app-in-a-single-html-file)

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn No I mean a static html file like you can run it by just open index.html file. Not run any command

Comment: I think you should try `npm run build`. From what I understand you want, this should do it. Works if you used create-react-app to build your project

Comment: @PiNaKa30 I've tried, but build folder still react app, you need run command "serve -s build" to start it

Comment: Then create-react-app website suggests 2 packages: [Pre-rendering into Static HTML](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/pre-rendering-into-static-html-files/)

Comment: Ok @PiNaKa30 I'll try it, thank you

Comment: right click Save as...

Answer (score 13):

I used [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to generate static html and javascript files.

[here](https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/getting-started-with-react-js-using-webpack-and-babel-66549f8fbcb8) is a good guide on how to start

Comment: Thank for your solution but that need deploy to a hosting, I just need a file index.html and more static files to run on my local

Comment: What are you using for scaffolding your app?

Comment: The webpack will create all your static files including the index file

Answer (score 3):

You need to pre render them with tools like
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snapshot
or
https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap

that actually make a snapshot of your current build but as plain html/css/js that can be run from any browser or even offline. There are also more advanced frameworks for this like Gatsby but this 2 should be enough for simpler problems.

Comment: helpful links, thanks.. I'd say remove the NPM repo `react-snapshot` link though (_edit: ..or change to it's GH link?_), since it's [`README.md` on GitHub](https://github.com/geelen/react-snapshot) says that it's deprecated, recommending `react-snap` in it's place anyway. (:

Answer (score 1):

The below code will give you the static file in the dist folder.

```
   const path = require('path');

   module.exports = {
      entry: './src/index.js',
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      }
    };
```

Then you can use below line code to send static files to browser, if you have express server:

```
app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Here put all your API route.

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const route = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html');
    res.sendFile(route);
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I prefer run by open index.html file than create and node server

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. From the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths) we can see that `package.json` entry of `homepage` makes THE difference, including deployment on GitHub pages which I have [written](https://layik.github.io/ghpages) about.

1. [Standard](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) CRA app
2. Edit `package.json` with `"homepage": "."`
3. Run `npm/yarn build`
4. On Linux `xdg-open build/index.html`

Your app should be running. And if the question is asking about embedding it in your custom HTML file then either use an iframe or link what is in the `index.html` file with the referenced element for React to render there.

Answer (score -1):

The product React delivers to your users is just javascript and html otherwise your clients wouldn't be able to render it, so build and run the react app, go to the page its being served at and just save it with the option "save as" in your browser. The folder you will get in return is your app with all the components and none of the react wizardry, just upload that to the public-html folder with your hosting provider and it will work no problem.